# download code via SWD ADuCM3029

Tags: microcontroller, swd, code, iar

I made my own PCB using ADUCM30299 as microcontroller;
in this card I also have a power management, BLE, Flash memory,USB Type C
when I tried to calculate the voltage in SWD_CLK, SWD_DATA, ....
I find that SWD_DATA always equal to 3V on the other hand SWD clock equal to 0.9v and when I click on reset button in my PCB it becomes 3V
This is the Schematic of the microcontroller ,

[image]
[image]

an someone explain to me and can I download my code in This board,
with Thanks

Comment: Have you used an SWD programmer to try and download the code? Can you tell me exactly which Analog board you copied? There are quite a few...

Comment: I copied the schematic of this Eval board : https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/eval-adicup3029.html#eb-overview

Comment: Ok, and what SWD programmer are you using?

Comment: the MK20DX128VFM5

Comment: That is a processor, not a programmer...